# Setting up virtual host/multiple stores on linux for opencart

Tags: linux, apache, opencart, virtual-hosts, lampp

I am using **Opencart 2.0** and I want to set up a virtual host for the second store. I am also using **Xampp** on **Kali Linux**. I have the main store at `/opt/lampp/htdocs/main_store/` and the url I am using to access it is `localhost/main_store` I have created a second store in the backend and I have set its url to `http:localhost/store_2`. I have edited my `/etc/hosts` and I have add my server name

```
   127.0.0.1    localhost
   127.0.1.1    hostname

   127.0.0.1    localhost/store_2
```

I have edited my `/opt/lampp/etc/extra/http.v-hosts.conf` and added

```
  # Sub domain localhost/store_2
 <VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot "/opt/lampp/htdocs/main_store/"
    ServerName localhost/store_2

    <Directory "/opt/lampp/htdocs/main_store/">
     Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews Includes 
     AllowOverride All 
     Order allow,deny 
     Allow from all 
     </Directory>
 </VirtualHost>
```

When I type `localhost/store_2`  I get an object not found error. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You cannot use `localhost/store_2` as a virtual host name, so this will not work in either your hosts file or VirtualHost config. `localhost` is your host name, `/store_2` is your directory (or application) name

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask. Also see [Where do I post questions about Dev Ops?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/134306)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Step 1:** Add your custom host in `/etc/hosts`. Execute this in your terminal

```
 sudo gedit /etc/hosts
```

Then add your custom host. For example my custom host is **mysite** so I have added `127.0.0.1 mysite`. In your case it is **store_2**

```
 127.0.0.1  localhost
 127.0.1.1  yourhostname

 127.0.0.1  mysite
```

**Step 2:**. Enable virtual hosts by editing httpd.conf

```
   sudo gedit /opt/lampp/etc/httpd.conf
```

Find *#Include etc/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf* and remove the # to un-comment this line

**step 3:** Add new virtual host by opening the httpd-vhosts.conf file

```
 sudo gedit /opt/lampp/etc/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf
```

Usually, by default there are two virtual hosts in this file. Comment these virtual hosts or delete them. For example in my case

```
#<VirtualHost *:80>
#ServerAdmin webmaster@dummy-host.example.com
#DocumentRoot "/opt/lampp/docs/dummy-host.example.com"
#ServerName dummy-host.example.com
#ServerAlias www.dummy-host.example.com
#ErrorLog "logs/dummy-host.example.com-error_log"
#CustomLog "logs/dummy-host.example.com-access_log" common
#</VirtualHost>

#<VirtualHost *:80>
#ServerAdmin webmaster@dummy-host2.example.com
#DocumentRoot "/opt/lampp/docs/dummy-host2.example.com"
#ServerName dummy-host2.example.com
#ErrorLog "logs/dummy-host2.example.com-error_log"
#CustomLog "logs/dummy-host2.example.com-access_log" common
#</VirtualHost>
```

Then add

```
 NameVirtualHost 127.0.0.1
 <VirtualHost 127.0.0.1> 
   DocumentRoot /opt/lampp/htdocs/
   ServerName localhost
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost mysite>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
    DocumentRoot /opt/lampp/htdocs/your_project_folder/
    ServerName mysite
    ServerAlias mysite
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteOptions inherit
    CustomLog /var/log/apache2/mysite.log combined
    <Directory /opt/lampp/htdocs/your_project_folder/>
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks Includes ExecCGI
        AllowOverride All
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

In the above code, in your case the project folder is **main_store**. Also replace **mysite** with your **store_2**

**Step 4:** Restart XAMPP server. This is very **IMPORTANT**

```
    sudo /opt/lampp/lampp restart
```

**Step 5:** Type `http://mysite/` in browser’s address bar and it should work. In your case `http://store_2/`